# Find non Identical values using Group by in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, distinct, having

I need to find the Non-Identical values are exist in a particular Group. Kindly have a look in the following Table `Contact`

```
ContactId    FirstName    LastName    Mobile
_________________________________________________

1            Emma         Watsan      9991234567
2            Jhon         Wick        8887654321
1            Emma         Watsan      9990001111
```

Here I need to fetch the **Emma Watsan** and need to find the Mobile numbers are Identical (bool - `bit`) If both Mobile numbers are Identical than `1` otherwise `0`.

I tried the following Query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Contact c 
GROUP BY c.ContactId, c.FirstName, c.LastName
HAVING COUNT(*) >1
```

Kindly assist me how to find the result.

Comment: Seems just change to `COUNT(DISTINCT Mobile) > 1`

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Select distinct a.ContactId, case when b.mobile is null then 0 else 1 end as [is_duplicate]
from Contact a 
left join Contact b 
on a.ContactId = b.ContactId 
and a.mobile = b.mobile
and a.id <> b.id
```

Where `[id]` is the primary key column in the table (you should have one).

Hope this helps.

PS: the table isn't normalized properly - if the ContactIDs repeat, the first and last name should not be in the same table.

Comment: IMO this won't work, because the `LEFT JOIN` will return the first row of Emma Watsan joined to itself and show as a duplicate, even though that row only exists once in the table.  He wants to compare different rows in the same table, not the same row.

Comment: Right. Edited. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

for get the infor related  to Emma Watsan you could ue

```
select * from Contact
where ContactId in ( 
  select c.ContactId FROM Contact c 
  group by c.ContactId 
  having  COUNT(*) >1
)
```

for get the Contacts  that have the same numebr

```
select c.ContactId,   COUNT(distinct Mobile) FROM Contact c 
group by  c.ContactId
having   COUNT(distinct Mobile)>1
```

Comment: Can we do this with the help of rank?

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi...   why ?  ... when sql  give the proper basic (and standard) function  .. why use  a function that is not standard or used by all the most common database ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Count(Distinct [Mobile])` to get the number of distinct mobile nmumbers per `ContactId`. And the use a `CASE` expression to give `0` or `1` based of the count. If count is greater than 1 then 0 else 1.

**Query**

```
select t.[Name], case when t.[Mobile] > 1 then 0 else 1 end as [Mobile_Identity] from(
    select ContactId, 
    max([FirstName] + ' ' + [LastName]) as [Name],   
    count(distinct [Mobile]) as [Mobile]
    from contacts
    group by ContactId
)t;
```

And if you want to retrieve only the rows with multiple mobile numbers, then use a `having` clause.

```
select t.[Name], case when t.[Mobile] > 1 then 0 else 1 end as [Mobile_Identity] from(
    select ContactId, 
    max([FirstName] + ' ' + [LastName]) as [Name],   
    count(distinct [Mobile]) as [Mobile]
    from contacts
    group by ContactId
    having count(distinct [Mobile]) > 1
)t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
  create table Contacts(ContactId int,FirstName varchar(15),LastName varchar(15),Mobile bigint)

    insert into Contacts
    select 1 ,'Emma','Watsan',9991234567
    union all
    select 2,'Jhon','Wick',8887654321
    union all 
    select 1,'Emma','Watsan',9990001111

    select c.ContactId, c.FirstName, c.LastName,IIF(cnt>1,1,0)ISIdentitcal
    from (
    SELECT c.ContactId, c.FirstName, c.LastName,
    COUNT(*)cnt FROM Contacts c 
    GROUP BY c.ContactId, c.FirstName, c.LastName)c
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it something like this...(sample table variable with data included)

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (ContactID INT, Firstname VARCHAR(55), Lastname VARCHAR(55), Mobile VARCHAR(55));

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (1, 'Emma', 'Watsan', '9991234567');
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (2, 'Jhon', 'Wick', '8887654321');
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (1, 'Emma', 'Watsan', '9990001111');
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (1, 'Emma', 'Watsan', '9990001111');

SELECT 
     T1.FirstName + ' ' + T1.LastName AS Name
    ,T1.Mobile
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN T2.RowID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS Duplicate
FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FirstName,LastName, Mobile) AS RowID
        ,*
    FROM @TABLE
    ) T1
LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FirstName,LastName, Mobile) AS RowID
        ,*
    FROM @TABLE
    ) T2
    ON T1.ContactID = T2.ContactID
    AND T1.Mobile = T2.Mobile
    AND T1.RowID <> T2.RowID
GROUP BY T1.FirstName + ' ' + T1.LastName, T1.Mobile
;
```

If the actual table already has row numbers, than the `row_number()` function can be skipped and the actual row ID of the table used in its place.

In the example here, Emma Watsan has the same number twice (on purpose), and another number that shows only once in the table.  The duplicate mobile number is marked (`Duplicate = 1`), but the other numbers are not, as desired.